# Applying conditions to different groups

Tags: python, pandas

```
       A     B     C     D
0    Red  10.0  11.5  12.0
1    Red  10.5  11.5  12.0
2    Red  11.0  11.5  12.0
3    Red  12.0  11.5  12.0
4  White  10.0  10.5  11.0
5  White  10.5  10.5  11.0
6  White  11.0  10.5  11.0
7  White  12.0  10.5  11.0
```

I want to apply next condition for each *A group*:

- If all `C values` are different of `B values` (it happens in *Red A group*, not in *White A group*): transform *C* in *D values*.

I mean, the result should be:

```
       A     B     C     D
0    Red  10.0  12.0  12.0
1    Red  10.5  12.0  12.0
2    Red  11.0  12.0  12.0
3    Red  12.0  12.0  12.0
4  White  10.0  10.5  11.0
5  White  10.5  10.5  11.0
6  White  11.0  10.5  11.0
7  White  12.0  10.5  11.0
```

I tried:

```
df.loc[(df["B"] != df["C"]) & (df["B"] == df["D"]), "C"] = df["D"]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby and then set C based on the comparison between B and C.

```
(
    df.groupby('A')
    .apply(lambda x: x.assign(C=x.D if x.B.ne(x.C).all() else x.C))
    .reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
)
Out[41]: 
       A     B     C     D
0    Red  10.0  12.0  12.0
1    Red  10.5  12.0  12.0
2    Red  11.0  12.0  12.0
3    Red  12.0  12.0  12.0
4  White  10.0  10.5  11.0
5  White  10.5  10.5  11.0
6  White  11.0  10.5  11.0
7  White  12.0  10.5  11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
df['C'] = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.D if np.all(x.B != x.C) else x.C).values
```

Group by column `A`. For each group if all the values in `B` are different from those in `C`, then return column `D`, else return column `C`.

The result of the `group by ... apply` operation is a series with a multi level index. The index is unimportant, so take the values and overwrite column `C`.

Comment: When I apply this sentence to my whole df, I get next ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. How could I proceed?

Comment: its hard to tell where the error is without seeing the whole code and stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Hey are you trying to copy all the values from D column to C column when A column == "Red". Then

```
df["C"][df["A"] == "Red"] = df["D"][df["A"] == "Red"]

Output
         A        B       C      D
    0   Red     10.0    12.0    12.0
    1   Red     10.5    12.0    12.0
    2   Red     11.0    12.0    12.0
    3   Red     12.0    12.0    12.0
    4   White   10.0    10.5    11.0
    5   White   10.5    10.5    11.0
    6   White   11.0    10.5    11.0
    7   White   12.0    10.5    11.0
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I think it doesn´t work for me, as my whole df has some more "A groups".

Comment: I have a wide expertise in DataFrame handling, so if you think we can connect may then I could help you better.